# How to use for loop in insert query mysql php?

Tags: php, mysql

```
$count=count($data);
for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++) {
    return execute("INSERT INTO tbl_adresses(postcode) VALUES (:postcode)", array(":postcode"=>$data[$i]['postcode']));
}
```

I need to get `$i` increment value to  be applied in insert query . I am always getting  `$i=0`.

Can Anyone tell me how to solve this?

Comment: Please put your code in code tags so its easier to read

Comment: And then go read up on what `return` does.

Comment: where are you incrementing the variable?

Comment: Doing a `foreach` would probably be a bit cleaner here. You're basically taking the long way and re-creating that functionality.

Comment: $data[$i]['postcode']. i need to insert various postcodes one by one in table

Comment: @NedunchezhianA read carefully 04FS's comment

Comment: @04FS is right, and a foreach will not help him with his problem now

Comment: Put your `return` outside of the `for` loop.